# python checking file changes without reading the full file

Tags: python, python-3.x, filesystems

I have a web app (in the backend) where I am using pysondb (https://github.com/pysonDB/pysonDB) to upload some tasks which will be executed by another program (sniffer).

The sniffer program (a completely separate program) now checks the database for any new unfinished uploaded tasks in an infinite loop and executes them and updates the database.

I don't want to read the database repeatedly, instead want to look for any file changes in the database file (db.json), then read the database only. I have looked into `watchdog` but was looking for something lightweight and modern to suit my needs.

```
# infinite loop
import pysondb
import time
from datetime import datetime

# calling aligner with os.system
import os
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

while True:
    # always alive
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        # process files
        db = pysondb.getDb("../tasks_db.json")
        tasks = db.getBy({"task_status": "uploaded"})

        for task in tasks:
            try:
                task_path = task["task_path"]
                cost = task["cost"]

                corpus_folder = task_path
                get_output =  subprocess.Popen(f"mfa validate {corpus_folder} english english", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
                res = get_output.read().decode("utf-8") 
                # print(type(res))
                if "ERROR - There was an error in the run, please see the log." in res:
                    # log errors
                    f = open("sniffer_log.error", "a+")
                    f.write(f"{datetime.now()} :: {str(res)}\n")
                    f.close()
                else:
                    align_folder = f"{corpus_folder}_aligned"
                    Path(align_folder).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
                    o = subprocess.Popen(f"mfa align {corpus_folder} english english {align_folder}", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().decode("utf-8")
                    # success

            except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
                # mfa align ~/mfa_data/my_corpus english english ~/mfa_data/my_corpus_aligned
                # log errors
                f = open("sniffer_log.error", "a+")
                f.write(f"{datetime.now()} :: Files not in right format\n")
                f.close()


    except Exception as e:
        # log errors
        f = open("sniffer_log.error", "a+")
        f.write(f"{datetime.now()} :: {e}\n")
        f.close()
```

Comment: monitor changes can be done with hashes ([old == new] no change in the file), but I can't say it's the fastest or suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

Using [python-rq](https://python-rq.org/) would be a much more efficient way of doing this that wouldn't need a database. It has no requirements other then needing a redis install. From there, you could just move all of that into a function:

```py
def task(task_path, cost):
    corpus_folder = task_path
    get_output =  subprocess.Popen(f"mfa validate {corpus_folder} english english", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
    res = get_output.read().decode("utf-8") 
    # print(type(res))
    if "ERROR - There was an error in the run, please see the log." in res:
        # log errors
        f = open("sniffer_log.error", "a+")
        f.write(f"{datetime.now()} :: {str(res)}\n")
    ... #etc
```

Obviously you would rename that function and put the try-except statement back, but then you could just call that through RQ:

```py
# ... where you want to call the function
from wherever.you.put.your.task.function import task
result = your_redis_queue.enqueue(task, "whatever", "arguments)
```